# How to identify type of 3-way switch wiring

Tags: electrical, multiway-switch, smart-switch

Like many others here, I am looking to replace a 3-way switch with a "smart switch" that requires neutral.
As I inspect my wiring (home built in 2009) I note that I can't tell the difference between two wiring schematics by looking at the switches themselves.

In looking up diagrams of these to add to this post, neither of these arrangements seems very common. I would add pictures of my switch boxes but they're both multi-switch boxes, one of which is very full and hard to track in-person, I can only imagine it'd be more confusing from photos. The other is extremely simple, 14/3 connected straightforwardly. I narrowed down my situation to 2 possibilities based on what I see.

Can a voltmeter or non-contact voltage tester help determine which of these I have? Or is there another way to tell without opening up the lights themselves? I found diagrams with 2 lights but I actually have 4 connected somehow to these 2 3-way switches.

Possibility 1:

[image]

Possibility 2:

[image]

EDIT: Adding photos of switch wiring.

Switch 2, which I found straightforward:

[image]

And here are two of Switch 1 which looked straightforward at first, but eventually I saw the black wire from the 14/3 does NOT go directly to the switch, it's coming from the 14/2 I marked in green (mspaint). I lose track of the black from 14/3 and the white from 14/2 as they go off to the left side of the box. Short of stretching all the nutted wire bundles out of the box, I'm convinced they're connected to each other (unless that doesn't make sense). I don't know that I can get all the wire bundles crammed back in the box as neatly as they are now so I've tried not to move them so far.

Switch 1:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add photos of the insides of the switch boxes anyway?  Also, have you tried looking inside the light fixture boxes for clues?

Comment: Use colored electrical tape to mark the travelers yellow.  You'll thank me later.   The 2 travelers are the ones going onto the brass/ yellow  screws.

Comment: Possibility 1 was drawn by a drunk skunk. It will not work.

Comment: I haven't looked in the light fixture boxes, these switches belong to 4 exterior lights. @Harper-ReinstateMonica Is that still true if you disregard the light fixtures? I have no idea what the connections look like inside them, I chose these diagrams because it matches what I see at the switches. I'm not sure if the 14/2 I see at Switch 1 is "power source" or coming from the series of lights, but knowing that would tell me if I have a neutral at the switch or not.

Comment: **DO NOT REMOVE WIRE NUTS!** At least not until you understand what's going on or, at an absolute minimum have marked all your wires so you know which ones went where! This place is _full_ of "I pulled all the nuts off my wiring and now I have no idea how to put it back together" questions

Comment: @FreeMan Good point, I facepalm when I see those posts too. I didn't mean remove them, I meant pull the whole bundle out of the box so I can see better. Regardless, I'd rather not do either unless necessary because they're pretty neatly/tightly crammed.

Comment: Possibility 1, as noted by Harper, is pretty much impossible. But in addition to Possibility 2: power -> lights -> switches, there is also Possibility 3: power -> switches -> lights. A little different, particularly because it guarantees you neutral at least at the *first* switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(This question is essentially dead and may never help someone else, but on the off chance that it might, I'm self-answering as I just installed the smart switch after about a year of procrastinating).*

I finally figured this out (with the help of a neighbor who is an electrician).

**The important part:**
We labeled the wires and disconnected them from both switches and did voltage testing with the breaker on and continuity testing with the breaker off. The breaker was also mislabeled so required a little trial-and-error to find and properly label it.

**Identification:**
It turns out all 3 of these switches in the Switch 1 box are on the same circuit and they all control lights in the same area. The white-painted-black and red going to the switch are indeed travelers. The black is Load on this side, it goes to the lights. Switch 2 black is Line, with white-painted-black and red travelers. I marked each of these travelers with yellow tape to help the next guy out.

**Conclusion:**
Switch 1 box has 2 bundles of Neutrals, I pigtailed off one of those for the smart switch. The smart switch I'm using (TP-Link HS210) is UL-listed (shout out to Harper for reminding us of the importance of this rating) AND designed for use as one end of a 3-way configuration - meaning I don't have to replace both switches and the remaining dumb Switch 2 still functions. This was important to me, as my wife doesn't want to be outsmarted by our smarthome.

Answer (score 3):

Actually since there are no white wires on the 3-ways, this gets simple.

The black and red wires that DO go to the 3-ways are part of cables.  Note which cables they are.  It matters.

Almost certainly, two cables are involved, and the 2 white wires in those cables are connected to each other.

As long as that's so, you can add the smart switch's white wire to those two white wires (might be more than 2).

Do keep in mind that with smart switches, often, the smart switch's design will dictate where it must go.  So don't just go "Imma puttin it there" and try to force it to work. Actually read the instructions and think about what you're doing.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I can't tell from looking at the switches whether I have power coming into switch 1 or if that 14/2 cable connects to the lights (with power connected at the lights). As @manassehkatz commented, it could be power -> lights -> switches or power -> switches -> lights. If it's power -> switches I should have neutral on that white from 14/2, if it's not then I wouldn't - right?

Comment: @fred on any “switch on the end” scenario, there would *have* to be a white wire (re-marked to be a hot) going to a switch.  There is none, therefore the switches are in the middle.

Comment: Both 3-ways have a black-painted white wire in the 14/3 cable going directly to the switch (the red and white-traveler switch sides on each switch - I don't think that matters). That's why I dug up the two diagrams I posted. I still don't know what the wiring looks like at the lights themselves; I was hoping there's a way to test from the easily-accessible switches and not have to open 4 light fixtures up high outside.

Comment: @FredShope That's a heck of a thorough painting job. Can't tell it's not a black. Following all 3 wires on the switch, are all 3 going into the same cable? On both switches?

Comment: @FredShope -- are you sure that you're seeing a white wire that was painted black, not a black wire that was painted (or plastered!!!) white?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I found it odd as well so I looked really hard at both ends. In both of them, they come directly out of the 14/3 cable and have a half-inch or an inch before the black paint starts, and the black paint scrapes off back to white if you rub it hard. Switch 2, the entire 14/3 cable attaches. Switch 1, the black from 14/3 goes off to the left of the box and the common terminal comes from a 14/2 cable, but the red and white(marked) from 14/3 go to the switch.

Comment: OK, so the red and white (marked) go to brass screws and are travelers.  (that's why I said mark travelers with yellow tape, way easier to sort this out). Anyway we know the installer was careful to follow Code, that's good.   The black that comes off common, probably has a white in its cable. It might be neutral (especially if unmarked).  If it joins other whites, that cinches it, that's your neutral.